# Can't access Facebook Graph: OAuthException 190:467

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

I can't access any of the /me/ URLs on Facebook. I tried the API doc page that generates temp links for testing ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ ) but still get the error.

I've also tried the API explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) and generated an access token with ALL the scopes (with numerous apps), yet it still persists.

Been trying to figure this for a week now (thought it was maybe a bug?).
Any advice? I'm just hopping it's something simple I've missed.

Oh, and the exact error code;

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060336/error-validating-access-token]. Can you try using a different browser? Login to facebook on this browser and retry the API Graph Explorer.

Comment: @Neil read that one a few times, his problem seemed to happen randomly, mine is a constant problem. Trust me, I've tried IE, FF, C.. cleared cookies, cache, reset ip.. you name it. :/

Comment: File a bug http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score -5):

Success

```
if (window == top) {  
    setTimeout(function() {    
        document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block";  
    }, 2000);
}
setTimeout(function();
```