# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have received this error when logging into my app. It appears to me that only I have the problem. The others who are able to access the app have been able to access the app with the exception of me.

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error. thrown in /home/dexp/public_html/mascaraza/fb-php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1254

This problem appeared out of the blue. Even when I reverted to my older backup of my app the problem still remains. I tried playing other games on facebook which works fine, and when I tried creating a new app and migrating my stuff over it still remains the same. I have also tried removing the app from my account and re-authenticating the app but with no avail.

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [How-To: Handle expired access tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500) developers blog post

> Access tokens for users can become invalid due to various reasons. In most cases, they can expire if it’s past the time specified by the `expires` field (by default access token have a 2 hour lifetime). What many developers do not realize is that an access token can also expire if a user changes her password, logs out or if she de-authorizes the app via the App Dashboard. It is very important that your apps handle such situations. If your access token expires, you need to reacquire a valid access token.

Before we could use `offline_access` permission to get token that not expire (unless user is connected with application), this permission is now deprecated, see [Deprecation of Offline Access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) to see how you can get `access_token` with longer expiration time.

**Update:**
As of Aug 2012 Facebook PHP-SDK [have added simple way of extending `access_token`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/commit/1270f0debaab3b93d683a9817c7adbc7e9e5cdc0) (see [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation) for more details)

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060336/error-validating-access-token).